# is there any module which gives domain list as content type field

Tags: domain-access

we are using domain access. we need to add domain list as a field to one content type so based on that result we need to display the result on main domain itself. is there any field module for it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That feature has been developed for the pending Drupal 8 release https://drupal.org/node/1917780 but is yet to be available for D7 (afaik)